# .exe files dissapear when they want in VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, conio

Things that i should note are that I am using the latest version of vs code to write in c, my compiler is mingw-w64. Whenever I run a simple code (Hello world for example) everything works then suddendly when I try to do something else a message appears saying (program name).exe was not found. This generally happens when I try to use commands from other libraries, i tries using conio.h textcolor() but it doesn't want to, but when i use getch() it works fine. Moreover the .exe file exists, then i add a single line of code and boom suddendly it doesn't exist. Can anyone explain to me what is going on??

Comment: Sounds like your compiler is cleaning up before rebuilding the executable, but then the build does not succeed and you don't get the executable. And no surprise here, `conio.h` is ancient MS-DOS thing that needs to be left to rest in it's grave.

Comment: Check any antivirus software you have running to make sure it isn't removing things. You may need to whitelist the directories where your projects are to avoid overly aggressive heuristics.